# Why did the Orville have the time capsule from 2015 on board?

Tags: the-orville

In Season 2, Episode 11 "Lasting Impressions", the *Orville* has recovered a time capsule from the year 2015. They examine its contents, and later in the episode, we hear staff members make arrangements to ship it to Earth.

Why did the Orville have this time capsule on board? I assume the time capsule was launched into space (otherwise, why take it off of Earth?), but even so, it couldn't have been sent that far from Earth without a quantum drive, and last episode the Orville was at the border of Krill space. So why is the Orville the first to examine it?

Comment: The 2 answers so far say they are transporting it from Earth to the Delta Pavonis system.  Since Delta Pavonis is only about 19.92 light years from Earth they should have come hundreds of light years inward from the border of Krill space.  I suspect the creators didn't think about how tiny the Union would be if Delta Pavonis was near the Krill border because they are not as familiar with the distances to various stars as a teenage amateur astronomer or science fiction fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Orville was transporting it from Earth to a museum in the [Delta Pavonis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_Pavonis) system.

> **Dr Sherman:** *The Delta Pavonis Museum is itching for its arrival.*
>
> **Kelly:** *Well, we'll get it all there in one piece.*
>
> <sub><sup>Orville: Lasting Impressions</sup></sub>

En route, they offer to help them perform a first-stage analysis of some of the technology that's been found. Which then sets up the rest of the show.

> **Dr Sherman:** *We think there still may be information stored in there, but the circuitry is so degraded, we haven't been able to reactivate it.*
>
> **Lamarr:** *Well, I got a top-notch engineering team.*
>
> <sub><sup>Orville: Lasting Impressions</sup></sub>

---

No indication is given as to why it would be moved from one place to another, except that moving it from one planet to another may be the futuristic equivalent of packing it up and fed-exing it to a specialist team in Los Angeles or Tokyo. Note that this also sets up Kelly's line in the next episode, where she compares their recent missions to being a glorified taxi services.

> **Admiral:** *You'll be picking up an engineer and transporting him to a research vessel in the Nekkar System.*
>
> **Kelly:** *Sir, with all due respect, we're starting to feel - like a taxi cab here.*
>
> <sub><sup>Orville: Sanctuary</sup></sub>

Answer (score 2):

### The Orville is transporting the time capsule from Earth to the Delta Pavonis system.

The episode begins with a Dr. Sherman showing the time capsule to the crew. During this scene it's explained that the time capsule was discovered on Earth and that the Orville is transporting it to a museum in another star system.

https://trekmovie.com/2019/03/22/review-the-orville-falls-for-the-past-in-lasting-impressions/
https://orville.fandom.com/wiki/Lasting_Impressions